# EF Core Custom Expression which gives sql IN

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to produce an expression which I will pass a list and will return the following

`where property IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3')`

This is my code

```cs
public class ExpressionBuilder : IExpressionBuilder
{
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetExpression<T>(string field, List<string> value)
    {
        ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");
        Expression exp = null;

        exp = GetExpression<T>(param, field, value);

        if (exp == null)
            return x => true;

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, param);
    }


    private Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression param, string field, List<string> values)
    {
        if (values == null)
            return null;

        try
        {
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(param, field);

            Expression final = null;
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                Expression constant = GetUnaryExpression(member, value);

                if (constant != null)
                {
                    final = final == null ? constant : Expression.And(final, constant);
                }
            }

            return final;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private Expression GetUnaryExpression(MemberExpression member, string value)
    {
        UnaryExpression constant;
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        constant = Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), member.Type);

        return Expression.Equal(member, constant);
    }
}
```

which produces the following:

`where property = 'value1' and property = 'value2' and property = 'value3')`

How can I produce the `IN` using the expression?

Comment: What about: `.Where(entity => values.Contains(entity.Column))`?

Comment: @Fabio I want to reuse this in several places

Comment: Can you show, how you are going to use it?

Comment: Why does it matter. The end result should be an Expression

Comment: Use `Expression.Or` rather than `Expression.And`. You now have functionally the same thing, since `IN` is rewritten as a series of `OR` clauses internally by the optimizer (well, when using SQL Server, at least; other servers may work differently).

Comment: I m using mysql and from what I read OR is slower than IN. That is why I am looking for a way to achieve IN

Comment: Well then your current approach is a dead end, since `IN` is an SQL-specific construct and it can't be represented directly in an `Expression`. You would need to hook into the bit that translates a custom invocation to SQL (or at least know what the .NET Core query builder will reliably translate to an `IN` clause, if there is any such thing). I don't know if that part of EF Core is extensible.

Comment: @pantonis, `Where .. Contains` can be reused everywhere, you provide entity type and strong typed property - same arguments you are passing to your method, oh and easy to understand as well ;)

Comment: @Fabio Contains is very easy to understand especially when you use string which creates a LIKE condition :) oh LIKE is not the same as IN (Equals) I think

Comment: Use `Expression.OrElse` and the smart EFC translator will turn it into `IN`